# GooglePlacesAPI - Too many API requests Issue

Tags: java, android, xamarin, google-places-api

So, I'm building an Android App using Xamarin for the first time. I am experienced in Android Studio using Java.

This app needs to take the user's current location, and find any restaurants/gas stations/grocery stores within a radius of 7km.

Then, it will remove certain results and display the list of places I'd like to see. But, I also need information like "Closing Time".

My problem is that I currently have to make an API call for each specific restaurant/place I want to search for within 7km of the User, which means 10+ calls (3+ seconds each) before going to my next activity (Painful!). Please, if anyone can help point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated! I've looked at the Radar Function in the Google Places API, but I can't configure it to do what I'd like it to.

Thanks again, cheers!